# Checking multiple textboxes/comboboxes for input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with multiple comboboxes and textboxes that I use to input data to the worksheet. What I have been looking for is a code that will check all of these boxes before saving the data to the worksheet, so if one is empty it will pop up a message and not save the data.

I have been using a function that checks each one individually but it'll still save data to the sheet if the others are blank.

```
Public Function CheckEmpty(text_box As Object) As Boolean
CheckEmpty = (Len(Trim(text_box.Value)) > 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try something like follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() '<== change "CommandButton1" with the actual 'closing' button name
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim msg As String

With Me
    For Each ctrl In .Controls

        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)

            Case "ComboBox"
                If ctrl.ListIndex = -1 Then msg = msg & vbCrLf & "ComboBox '" & ctrl.name & "' with no value selected"
            Case "TextBox"
                If ctrl.text = "" Then msg = msg & vbCrLf & "TextBox '" & ctrl.name & "' with no value selected"
            Case Else

        End Select

    Next ctrl

    If msg = "" Then
        .Hide ' hide the userform only if no empty textboxes and/or comboboxes
    Else
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation + vbInformation
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

to be placed in the UserForm code pane

Comment: Glad to be of help. If I fulfilled your question then please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the checkbox control objects, and then iterate on it checking each object in turn.

Comment: This is kind of what I put together and it keeps telling me it is not empty, I am new to all of this so bear with me:    Dim Test(1 To 10) As Variant
Set Test(1) = TextBox1
Set Test(2) = TextBox2
Set Test(3) = TextBox3
Set Test(4) = ComboBox1
Set Test(5) = ComboBox2
Set Test(6) = ComboBox3

If IsEmpty(Test) Then
MsgBox "its empty"
Else
MsgBox " its not"
End If